# Is there a smart way open a node js server on your website while still using php

Tags: php, node.js

i have a website where you click on a tomato and get points based on how many times you've klicked on it. The problem is that it's all running on php and AJAX requests. Every 10 seconds an request is sent on how many clicks the user has now, and the server updates. So in theory a user could just send requests of them having 30000 clicks and it would register. A friend of mine said that i should use node and register every click individualy with a socket, but everything so far is running on php. Is there a way to open a node server and make it talk with php?

Comment: So is there any difference between sending something saying they have doe 30000 clicks or sending 30000 requests saying they have clicked it.  If they can code, they could set up a loop and just let it run.

Comment: I fail to see why a node server should offer any advantage here. You would still be using the http protocol and you still would have to decide whether you want to report every single click or batches of clicks. Comes out the same. Instead take a look at websockets which might be more of a help since they allow to keep open the connection, thus eliminating the protocol overhead which might make it possible to register each single click. Though, quite frankly, I fail to see the point of all this.